# How to add a Cast (Chromecast) button to a ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview, chromecast

I have a ListActivity and I would like to add a Cast button to the menu of this activity. In order to do this, the activity has to extend ActionBarActivity (instead of ListActivity) and use a different style in the AndroidManifest.xml (Them.AppCompat as opposed to AppTheme) which make the list look very different.

Also, my menu had several items, but now only the Cast button is showing up.

Any suggestions on how to maintain the ListActivity properties, but still add a Cast button to the menu?

Thank You,
Gary

Comment: If you are seeking a `MediaRouteActionProvider`, see my CWAC-MediaRouter project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-mediarouter

Comment: That's exactly what I am seeking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways, depending on how much flexibility you have and how much work you are willing to do:

- See if you can change your activity to inherit from FragmantActivity or ActionBarActivity; then you can still have your list there but as a, say, fragment (e.g. ListFragment). If you can make such a change, Cast button can be added very easily.
- If you cannot change that, then you need to have a fully custom solution; you need to add the cast icon/menu and then manage that yourself, you might want to look at this sample [project](https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android).

As for the theme, in the first option above, you probably want to have your theme inherit from the AppCompat and then customize that accordingly.